# android radiogroup, radiobutton, button same line

Tags: android

i have activity like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
                android:text="status"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/radioButtonAll"
                        android:text="all"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                        android:checked="true" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
                        android:text="add"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        app:buttonTint="#ffffff" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/radioButtonDelete"
                        android:text="delete"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

                </RadioGroup>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
                    android:text="Select"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_select"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

this is result :
TextView_______________________________________________________
_________________________________________________Button________
RadioButton1_____RadioButton2____RadioButton3_____________________

but I want like this :
TextView____________________________________________________
RadioButton1_____RadioButton2____RadioButton3_____________Button

that mean RadioGroup with 3 RradioButton and Button same line(Button will stay right & end of line)
how to fix it?

update :
this is code I follow Sathish Kumar J, but it still like that :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
                android:text="status"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonAll"
                    android:text="all"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:checked="true"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
                    android:text="add"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonDelete"
                    android:text="delete"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
                android:text="Select"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/button_select"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Comment: yes, but still like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this answer and let me know

with LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
            android:text="status"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"

        >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonAll"
                android:text="all"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                android:checked="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
                android:text="add"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonDelete"
                android:text="delete"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
            android:text="status"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonAll"
                android:text="all"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                android:checked="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
                android:text="add"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonDelete"
                android:text="delete"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this put weight and layout to match parent**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSelect"
            android:text="status"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
                android:layout_weight="0.80"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonAll"
                    android:text="all"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonAdd"
                    android:text="add"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonDelete"
                    android:text="delete"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:buttonTint="#ffffff"/>

            </RadioGroup>

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSelect"
                android:text="Select"

                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/button_select"/>
         </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Button will stay right & end of line, but not same line with RadioButton

Comment: try update answer take layout and android:layout_gravity to left to button and take weight as you want

Comment: i don't understand "take layout and android:layout_gravity to left to button ".

Comment: if it try place Button in RadioGroup in xml, all of it will same line, but Button not stay in right & end of line.

Comment: I was try, but it not same I want

Comment: set radiogroup weight 0.40 and LinearLayout 0.60 than try

Answer (score 0):

Try with `layout_weight`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup_select"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

               <RadioButton 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="op1"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>

               <RadioButton 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="op2"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>


               <RadioButton 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="op3"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>


               <RadioButton 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="op4"
                   android:layout_weight="1"/>


            </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Screenshot

[image: Answer]

this might helps you

Comment: I see, but my view still like that.

Comment: i don't know why, but my view still like that

Comment: if it try place Button in RadioGroup in xml, all of it will same line, but Button not stay in right & end of line.